# Pod Lock file changes with with included sub modules within team

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, git-submodules

I'm not sure if this is an issue caused by my Git configuration or CocoaPods but I am suffering the annoyance at the cocoapod end. Our team configuration is using CocoaPods and Git and we are keeping the Pod.lock file version controlled as well as the Podfile. The issue arises between commits within the team.
We have external sources included in the Podfile and the resulting Podlock includes section like this after one person commits:

```
EXTERNAL SOURCES:
SubModuleOne:
  :path: ./SubModules/SubModuleOne
SubModuleTwo:
  :path: ./SubModules/SubModuleTwo
SubModuleThree:
  :path: ./SubModules/SubModuleThree
```

After pulling and rebasing on a different machine and trying to compile I get the warning about the podlock being out of date and `pod install` needs to be run. 
After doing that the project runs and compiles but there are quotes added around the above paths. like this:

```
EXTERNAL SOURCES:
SubModuleOne:
  :path: "./SubModules/SubModuleOne"
SubModuleTwo:
  :path: "./SubModules/SubModuleTwo"
SubModuleThree:
  :path: "./SubModules/SubModuleThree"
```

If I commit these then it causes the same issue on other machines. Even though, functionally both seem to achieve the same result it is annoying an triggering the need to do unnecessary pod installs on every commit and merge.

Comment: Do you have the same version of `pod` utility on all machines?

Comment: we have the same version of cocoapods and Git. Also the same for MacOSX and Xcode